# Unable to run unit test from importing function - Python

Tags: python, testing

I feel like I may be missing something very obvious here, but when I create a class for a unit test within my main Python file I am able to run the unit test successfully. However, when I try to import the class into a separate test.py file, there is absolutely no output. The two .py files are located in the same directory. Here is some of the code from the test file:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/path/to/files')
import unittest
from mainfilename import Fraction

#Class for unit test
class TestOperatorEval(unittest.TestCase):

    #Create instances of Fractions
    def SetUp(self):
        self.Fraction = Fraction()

    #For successful test cases
    def test_OperatorEval_success(self) -> None:
        # Fractions to test
        f49: Fraction = Fraction(4, 9)
        f15: Fraction = Fraction(1, 5)
        f2945: Fraction = Fraction(29, 45)

        self.assertEqual(f49.__add__(f15), f2945)
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
    main()
```

This same block of code runs perfectly fine with a passed test when it's in the main file. What could I do next to troubleshoot?

Edit: Fraction is a class created to perform mathematical operations on fractions, e.g.:

```
#Define the Fraction class
class Fraction:
    #Method for the numerator and denominator
    def __init__(self, numerator: float, denominator: float) -> None:
        #Store numerator and denominator
        self.num: float = numerator
        self.denom: float = denominator

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        #Return instances of Fraction in desired format
        return str(self.num)+"/"+str(self.denom)

    #Method to sum fractions
    def __add__(self, otherFraction: object) -> "Fraction":
        #Get numerator of new fraction
        othernumerator: float = self.num * otherFraction.denom + self.denom * otherFraction.num
        #Get denominator of new fraction
        otherdenominator: float = self.denom * otherFraction.denom
        #Return instance of fraction
        return Fraction(othernumerator, otherdenominator)
```

Comment: What is `Fraction`?

Comment: @Mike67 Please see the edit for a sample of the main file code